# OCaml performance according to matching order

Tags: performance, pattern-matching, ocaml

In OCaml, is there any relation between the order in a pattern-matching and performance?

For instance, if I declare a type:

```
type t = A | B | C
```

and then perform some pattern-matching as follows:

```
match t1 with
  | A -> ...
  | _ -> ...
```

From a performance point of view, is it equivalent to

```
match t1 with
  | B -> ...
  | _ -> ...
```

assuming in the first case there are as many A's as there are B's in the second?

In other words, should I worry about the order of declaration of constructors in a type, when considering performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a paper explaining how pattern-matching is compiled in OCaml:
“Optimizing Pattern Matching”, L. Maranget and F. Le Fessant, ICFP’01

It basically says that the semantics is "in order", but that it is usually compiled in the optimal way, independently of the order of lines. Values of constructors don't matter either, it's the number of constructors that makes the difference, i.e. if it is compiled by a tree of comparisons, or by a jump table.

Optimality + exhaustivity test makes pattern-matching in OCaml probably the most wonderful feature of the language, and is much more efficient that writting cascades of "if" manually.

Answer (score 2):

This is an impossible question to answer carefully. However, in practice if you have a type whose constructors are all nullary (i.e., equivalent to small integers), and there are more than a very few of them, but less than a whomping huge pile of them, the code generator will almost certainly use a hardware jump table, which has essentially the same performance for each possible value.

In general, I wouldn't worry about things like this at all until you have identified the slow parts of your code. But there's almost no chance you would be able to speed things up by reordering a set of nullary constructors.

Comment: Could the results be different for list constructors, then? For instance, if I'm dealing with large lists and therefore know the "empty list" case will happen much less often, should I always put it last in the pattern-matching?

Comment: You should write your code to be as clear as possible. There is a lot of good research and effort devoted to making pattern matching as fast as possible. Other than that, I think there are too many possibilities in complex pattern matching to give a useful answer. (Perhaps somebody more knowledgeable will be willing.)

Comment: @dhekir Pattern-matching is done “as if in order”. If there is no overlap between cases, as is the case between empty list and nonempty list, the compiler already orders them as it pleases.